# OpenCL How to read and write to VRAM array

Tags: parallelization, eigenvalues, opencllink

I am quite a newbie to OpenCLLink. My program needs to perform some heavy computations on GPU including solving the eigenvector problems. Since I didn't find a straightforward implementation of this algorithm on GPU I added CPU instructions. Therefore, It was necessary to read/write values from VRAM, but actually only one element per iteration.

OpenCLLink doesn't provide I/O functions acting on a single element, sooo, I wrote a stupid kernel function for it

```
__kernel void extract(
    __global   float4* spin,
    __constant   float4* pos,

    mint number,

    __global float4* s
)

{
    if(get_global_id(0) == 0) {

    
        s[0] = spin[number];
        s[1] = pos[number];
    }
}

 __kernel void insert(
    __global   float4* spin,
    __constant   float4* pos,

    mint number,
    __constant float4* s
)

{
    if(get_global_id(0) == 0) spin[number] = s[0];
}
```

Then, I measured the time spent on those operations in the main loop of the program

```
1000*{

    (extract[spin, pos, #, ext, 1])//AbsoluteTiming//First,

    (s = OpenCLMemoryGet[ext])//AbsoluteTiming//First,

    (calcFields[spin, pos, s[[2]], Jxx, Jyy, Jxy, DIP, tresh, 256*4, field, Length[supercell]])//AbsoluteTiming//First,

    (force = Take[Total[OpenCLMemoryGet[field]], 3])//AbsoluteTiming//First,

    eigensolve//AbsoluteTiming//First,

    insert[spin, pos, #, Join[s[[1]], {0.}], 1]//AbsoluteTiming//First

}&/@ RandomInteger[{0, Length[supercell]-1}, 1000]//Mean
```

which results in

```
{1.69889,0.320111,3.23853,0.336236,0.454844,2.59156}
  ^^^^                                       ^^^^
```

that means, the time spent on reading and writing a single element in `spin` array has the same order of magnitude as the time needed for the actual GPU computation happening in `calcFields`.

Are there any ways how to access VRAM without copying the whole array?
Or is there some straightforward implementations of `Eigensystem[]` even for a single core in OpenCL?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this mix of GPU and CPU computation should defeat the purpose of using the GPU. As you have seen yourself, the communication overhead dominates. So you should try to perform the eigen decomposition in the GPU.

Comment: As for the eigensolver: A brief google search tells me that there have been some attempts to make the popular C++ library "eigen" available on the GPU. I don't know what came out of this. Probably the project died along with the general audience's interest in the whole OpenCL project...

Comment: Thanks, Henrik. I was also thinking to get rid of this unnecessary step. Also, the question is, should I implement it as a separate kernel function? Is it possible to construct something like a pipeline?

Comment: That depends a lot on the size and number of the eigenvalue problems. If you have to solve many smallish eigenvalue problens (small means matrices of size $n \times n$ with $n$ small enough so that the matrices fit into the local worker's own memory), then you should put the eigensolve into the same kernel as the other tasks if possible. My experience with GPU programming is quite limited (and probably quite outdated), but IIRC there is also a nonnegligible penalty for the workers grabbing data from GPU's global memory, in particular if this is done out-of-order.

Comment: So you want to minimize the number of memory reads and writes of the workers into global memory and pack as many computations as possible into each kernel. I guess.

Comment: If you want to do eigensolves for larger dense matrices or for large sparse arrays, then things are quite nontrivial. I have no idea how these things are implented on GPUs. And probably the only implementations that you will find are in CUDA, not in OpenCL.

Comment: Thank you for your rich answers. Actually, yeah, the issue is to find eigenvalues of a small matrix after each iteration. Since my approach is based on the Monte-Carlo method I need to make only one worker or one group solve the problem. I will try clMagma as well

Comment: Since OpenCLLink has a massive problem with memory leaking, I think it is better to write some simple wrapper in C/C++ and communicate with Mathematica via TCP